Rigify Export To Unity Animation Break
So I'm having a problem with rigify. Couldn't find solution online but also, don't know how to search for the nature of the problem in the first place since I'm new to this.
Spend many hours breaking my head over why the export animations from blender to unity in FBX breaks the animations. I'm trying to animate hands with weapon. In blender everything looks fine yet after export to unity objects, meaning hands and weapon, move slightly out of sync.
Basically to troubleshoot, I noticed that meta rig doesn't move, so Iv tried creating the same animation only using metarig(bones) instead of the rig that rigify generates and it worked perfectly fine with no lag or de sync.
Every video that I watched on rigify tells to hide the bones since you don't need them after generating and parenting the rigify rig, non of which mention such possible problem.
Question I have therefore, What am I doing wrong? What did I miss?.
Or is this how it is?
Here is the image of my rigify setup.

Here file:

Hello. If you have a reference Blender file, you might get some good answers. Please use this link to post the file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Can't I just hand the parent bone as specified?
I believe you could make the specified bone parented on the unity side. (by drag and drop).
In this case, the location of the weapon should be (0,0,0).
Only the rotation of the weapon may need to be changed to match the angle of the arm.



Thanks, that's solved the issue, yet I'm still a bit confused. What is this DEF-hand.R? I couldn't find it visual on rig, only in list like you showed, I didn't know they even existed. What are they part of?

Sorry, I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to do this. Normally, you can just parent the output destination "hand.R". By the way, I think "DEF" is a connection identifier meaning deformation. figfy is complex and has various auxiliary bones.
